How to I use VBA in excel 2016 to fill blank cells with same values as in the cells above?
I created a form that collects data from 2 different sheets, and in the output sheet if there are blank cells they need to be filled with values as written above
Sub FillBlanksProtocol()
    Dim wsProtocol As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim row As Long
    On Error Resume Next

    ' Set the Protocol sheet
    Set wsProtocol = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Protocol")

    ' Determine the last row in column A
    LastRow = wsProtocol.Cells(wsProtocol.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

    ' Loop through columns A:H (1 to 8)
    For col = 1 To 8
        For row = 2 To LastRow ' Start from row 2 to avoid referencing non-existent rows
            With wsProtocol
                ' Check if the current cell is empty
                If IsEmpty(.Cells(row, col).Value) Then
                    ' Stop copying if there is data to the left
                    If col > 1 And Not IsEmpty(.Cells(row, col - 1).Value) Then Exit For

                    ' Fill the current cell
                    If col = 1 Then
                        ' For column A: Increment the value from the cell above
                        If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(row - 1, col).Value) Then
                            .Cells(row, col).Value = .Cells(row - 1, col).Value + 1
                        End If
                    Else
                        ' For other columns: Copy the value from the cell above
                        If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(row - 1, col).Value) Then
                            .Cells(row, col).Value = .Cells(row - 1, col).Value
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        Next row
    Next col

    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub


I tried looping through

Could you share relevant sample data using this Table to Markdown Generator so we have something to work with? Simply copy not more than 21 relevant rows (including the headers) of the table into the big text box, press Submit, press Copy and paste it into your post (question). Do this for the before and the after. Also, share more detail about the requirement and what exactly is wrong with the code.

' Stop copying if there is data to the left ? Why ?

Option Explicit

Sub FillBlanksProtocol()
    Dim wsProtocol As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, c As Long, r As Long

    ' Set the Protocol sheet
    Set wsProtocol = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Protocol")
    With wsProtocol
        ' Determine the last row in column A
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

        ' Start from row 2 to avoid referencing non-existent rows
        For r = 2 To LastRow
            ' Loop through columns A:H (1 to 8)
            For c = 1 To 8
                ' Check if the current cell is empty
                If IsEmpty(.Cells(r, c)) Then
                    If c = 1 Then
                        ' For column A: Increment the value from the cell above
                        .Cells(r, c) = .Cells(r - 1, c) + 1
                    Else
                        ' For other columns: Copy the value from the cell above
                        .Cells(r, c) = .Cells(r - 1, c)
                    End If
                End If
            Next c
        Next r
    End With
    
End Sub

